# Detect Enter key is pressed with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I have a text field which is showing a value. What I want is when the user writes a new value in that text field and presses <kbd>enter</kbd>, an ajax function is triggered to do a pagination operation. I have a text field like this:

```
<input type="text" id="page" name="page" value="<?php echo($this->pn);?> />
```

And when a user writes any new value and presses <kbd>enter</kbd>, I want the following ajax function triggered:

```
update_ajax2({rpp:<?php echo($this->rpp);?>,pn:document.page.paged.value,filter:'<?php echo($this->filter);?>',orderby:'<?php echo($this->orderby);?>'});
```

I tried using the keypress event to detect `if(e.which===13)` but this doesn't solve the problem. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Why doesn't acting on the `keypress` event solve the problem? Do you get an error? Have you tried `keyup` instead?

Comment: @ctcherry it calls the function 2 types on 1 key press. First it loads the value that I want and then on same key press it loads function fo the `value` attribute of textbox

Answer (score 150, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="txt">

$('#txt').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('you pressed enter ^_^');
    }
})
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VCdEn/).

**Update (June 2022)**

Note that [keyCode has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode). Use `KeyboardEvent.code` or `KeyboardEvent.key` properties instead:

```
if (e.key === "Enter") {
   // Pressed enter
}
```

Comment: @experimentX thanks dude but it is always having the value that is in `value` attribute of textbox. It doesn't detects new value....

Comment: @AwaisQarni could you post a fiddle??

Comment: @AwaisQarni i mean on http://jsfiddle.net or update mine http://jsfiddle.net/VCdEn/

Comment: @AwaisQarni ... nope.. its not due to value. it's due to the form element. i.e. form is being submitted(as default). to prevent it. `e.preventDefault()` update here http://jsfiddle.net/FxU9X/6/

Comment: Standard usability says to use key-up event instead of key-down. It gives them the option to cancel after key down by pressing a modifier (like esc) before lifting up. Also it is how most libraries will catch the event so it brings consistency. Keydown is for data entry and key up is for events.

Answer (score 4):

Use this, it works for me :)

```
$("#search-txt" ).on( "keydown", function(event) {
    if(event.which == 13) 
        return false;//do something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this plugin: https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

Answer (score 0):

Key pressed event should work try it

```
function keyPressedTest(a)
{
    a=(a)?a:window.event;
    input=(a.target)?a.target:a.srcElement;
    if(a.keyCode==13)
    {
        your_function()
    }
}
```