# any way of making iFrame work without clicking?

Tags: html, iframe

I am using an iFrame to load a page whose url is specified in a text box. Here is my code :

```
<iframe id="import_url_iframe">

</iframe>
```

I use jQuery change event to get the change of the url in the text box :

```
    $("#wiki_form_url").change(function(){

        var value = $(this).val();
        $("#import_url_iframe").attr("src", value);

    });
```

This works fine if I click outside after specifying the url in the text box. But, I need to make this so when I write the url in the text box, it should show the page in iFrame (without any click outside). How can I accomplish that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an keydown event, possibly with a delay so that it loads after a delay (i.e. when the user hasn't typed for X seconds). So:

```
var timeout = null;
$("#wiki_form_url").on('keydown', function(){
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        // load URL here
    }, 1000);
});
```

And implementing @JCOC611's suggestion as well, taking code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631589/detect-enter-key-is-pressed-with-jquery), add this code as well:

```
$("#wiki_form_url").on('keydown', function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        timeout = null;
        // Load URL here
    }
})'
```

You could take it further still, and add handlers for when the text box loses focus

```
$("#wiki_form_url").on('focusout', function (){
    timeout = null;
    // Load URL here
})'
```

Comment: +1 And maybe even consider loading the iFrame after the user presses enter...you should try to avoid unnecessary requests to servers.

Comment: I tried your code :     var timeout = null;
    $("#wiki_form_url").on('keydown', function(){
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            // load URL
            $("#import_url_iframe").attr("src", value);
        }, 10);
    });

but unfortunately its not working for me. And, I can't press enter because the text field for url is part of a form, and if I press enter the form is submitted which I don't want at this stage. I will have other fields in the form to be filled up by the user after seeing the loaded page in the iFrame.

Comment: @Jodes thanks for your help. But, it's still not working for me. What I really want to accomplish is: I enter an url in the textbox and want to see the page loaded in my iframe without doing anything else. (no extra click, enter nothing). Is this possible?

Comment: What happens if you add `alert('test')` to the code with `setTimeout`, in place of the `// load URL here` comment? Does it trigger? Do you get any errors?