# How to update an entry by pressing enter in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php and want to create a form where the user has to enter data in different rows where each row represent a single data point. I want to design it in such a way that whenever data is entered against any row, that particular data point is updated and stored in mysql server without waiting for rest of the entries. It should happen as soon as data is entered in a particular cell. Pressing of return should trigger update in mysql server. Is it possible to do so in php or I need to use some other technology

Comment: you need javascript/ajax, i think

Comment: I would not suggest a beginner to use ajax / JS. Hitting enter in an HTML form does also submit (if not in an multi row `<textarea>`). Rather start with the basics. What is `$_GET`, what is  `$_POST`, how does Mysqli or PDO work, ...

Comment: @DanFromGermany I got the basics of PHP from net and have already designed the $_GET and $_POST forms. I had doubts and hence in the last line hinted if PHP would be sufficient to do this

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, PHP is a server side language and it offers no interaction with the client since it just runs on the server. For things like that you should use Javascript/JQuery and fire an event once the return key is pressed, for example:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
        key = {enter: 13}; //You can add more key definitions here
        switch (keyCode) {
            case key.enter: { //key.enter refers to 13
                alert('Enter was pressed');
                //Inside here you can do your post calls to PHP but I'm not very sure on what you want to accomplish once the key is pressed down.
            }
        }
});
```

Here's a similar question to yours: [Detect Enter key is pressed with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631589/detect-enter-key-is-pressed-with-jquery)
You can find more about JQuery at: http://jquery.com/
The documentation for the JQuery API can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: +1 for including some cool jQuery code. But prepare to get downvoted by DanFromGermany, who thinks that the asker is not ready for javascript.

Comment: Thank you. Being upvoted or downvoted is pretty much the same for me, I'm all about learning. It's not the reputation I care about but how much I learn if I commit a mistake. I mean, I'm all about learning but I always try to answer as correctly as I can the way I would like to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

In my answer, i focus on the part in your question where you mention that the updates should take place one cell at a time, and make the assumption that you do not want the whole form to be submitted - possibly with unwanted dummy data for the not-yet-entered cells.

You cannot do that using *only* PHP. PHP runs on the server, the code cannot react on events happening in the browser. You need to combine the PHP server code with JavaScript client code.

Since the user is supposed to continue entering into the same form, the solutions pointing out how to submit the form will not be sufficient. When the form submits, the page will also reload.

To achieve sending of one cell at the time, you need Ajax. Ajax can be a bit complicated to use cross-browser if old versions of especially Internet Explorer is to be supported. Therefore, i would recommend you to use jQuery for your Ajax requests. jQuery takes care of the cross-browser issues for you.

jQuery can also help you get the data from the form field. If you let your PHP code output HTML similar to:

```
<input type="text" class="datapoint" name="datapoint1" value="default value" />
<input type="text" class="datapoint" name="datapoint2" value="default value" />
...
```

then what you aim to learn in jQuery is how to write something similar to:

```
$(document.ready(function() {  // This is a way to have jQuery bind the desired actions when the page is built in the browser. 
    $('.datapoint')  // Finds all elements in the document with class="datapoint"
    .on("change", function () {  // Binds an action to execute when the value is changed - detected when the input loose focus, i.e. when the user moves to the next cell
         var params = { name: $(this).attr('name'), value: $(this).attr('value') };  // Extracts name and value from the input field changed
         $.ajax({
             url: updatevalue.php, 
             data: params
         });
    }); 
}); // Ends the $(document.ready(function() {
```

On the server, you need to back this code with `updatevalue.php` (or other URL of your choice), something similar to:

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name']; 
$value = $_REQUEST['value']; 

switch ($name) {
    case 'something': 
        // Prepare PDO statement
        break; 
    case 'something else': 
        // Prepare some other PDO statement
        break; 

    ... 
}

... execute PDO ...
```

For a beginner in PHP, i recommend learning to use PDO for database access. Please make sure to use prepared statements in PDO, see the PHP manual for how to do that.

Also, remember **not** to use the `name` value to build a dynamic SQL expression similar to this:

```
$query = 'UPDATE myTable SET '.$name.'=:value'; // Very bad idea!
```

because that would introduce a huge security hole in your application.

There is still something missing. What to put in your `WHERE` clause?

Depending on the specifics of your use case, a quick and i hope fairly easy to understand approach is to use the `data` attribute in HTML. The browser support isn't complete, but it works in all modern browsers. The snippets above changes to:

```
var params = { name: $(this).attr('name'), value: $(this).attr('value'), recordid: $(this).data('recordid') };
...
<input type="text" class="datapoint" name="datapoint1" data-recordid='1234' value="default value" />
```

The answer this far do not answer your question, because this do not let your user press enter to update a cell. It does let the user tab through the input fields, and the database will be updated when the user leaves the field.

To let the user press enter to update an individual value, you must also:

1. Make sure that hitting enter do not submit the complete form.
2. Make sure that hitting enter triggers the change event on the input.

For those, you can modify Ignacio Belhot Colistro:s answer to use

```
$('.datapoint').keydown(function (e) {
```

instead of `$(document). ...` and

```
e.preventDefault(); 
$(this).blur(); // As if the user tabbed or clicked to focus on some other element
```

instead of `alert`.

Caution: This is an easy way to code it. It is, however, very inefficient to construct and attach a new function to the keydown event for a lot of elements in a page. If you have a lot of fields then this approach might give you performance problems. In that case, using some ready-made plugin (like the one in Buttle Butkus answer) is probably your best solution.

The caution above is valid for all my snippets. They should all be tuned and completed. But this answer is already too lengthy, and i believe this might the most realistic way for a beginner to achieve the detailed functionality you ask for.

I hope this might help you to at least get started in a good direction.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use javascript and ajax.

Personally, I use the jeditable jquery plugin. You can set it to update on ENTER, or have it require a button click. Input can be text box or dropdown, etc. It's very cool.

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Examples:

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html

I suggest you start working on it now and post your questions about the code here at stack overflow. Your current question isn't really a code question and will get downvoted.

Comment: Do you really think, someone asking if PHP handles ENTER events should start with jQuery / ajax? I'm close to downvote your answer because it is not useful for a beginner and doesn't explain shit

Comment: @DanFromGermany just because someone doesn't know php does NOT mean he doesn't know jquery/ajax. it is like apples and oranges. you can't compare.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I don't know if he knows jQuery/ajax, but this happens to be EXACTLY where I started learning it. It took about 2 days. I'm sorry if it was hard for you.

Comment: When I started programming for the Internet, there was no Ajax, and when I started with Ajax, there was no jQuery. Scriptkiddies ;)

Comment: I started well after ajax was invented. And I started with jeditable. So, no, I don't think it's too soon. You google the crap out of everything and in a day or two of hard work you've got a working AJAX based form working.