# Javascript/jQuery : Detect both return key press and submit button press simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, time

I have an input field and an "add" button below it. What the add button basically does is, it appends a new input field to the document. What I am trying to do here is, while typing in an input field if return key press is detected the function that calls the addition of new input field is fired the same function that is fired when the add button is clicked.

Can I incorporate the detection of return key press in the following somehow?

```
$('.addNewSite').on('click', function(){


          var idNewInput = "site" + numInputFields;
          $('.inputFieldsSettingsPanel').append('<input type="text" class="tracksiteInput" id = "' + idNewInput + '"></input>');
          $("#" + idNewInput).focus();

});
```

Comment: The keypress should be detected by the input field. Don't you think?

Comment: So why not post the code that appends the input field, if that's the element you want to add an event handler to. An empty function that's not related to the problem doesn't help much

Comment: I read this a few times and don't quite understand. Can you please share more of your code in a concise example?

Comment: Do you mean the 2 events do the same thing? Just create the function to add the new field separately and bind the 2 events to it, like `function addField(){};  $('.addButton').on('click', addField); $('input').on('keypress', addField);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect Enter key is pressed with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631589/detect-enter-key-is-pressed-with-jquery)

Comment: @Juhana Not a duplicate. I am not trying to just detect the key press but make the same function run on both a key press and click on a button

Comment: So you know how to detect an enter keypress? Where's your code for that?

Comment: If you create elements with jQuery, as in `$('<input />')` it's easy to add attributes and event handlers during creation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/cy84t4pz/

```
function fun(){
$('body').append('<input type="text"/>');
}

$('.addButton').on('click', fun);

$('body').on('keypress','input', function(e){
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
       fun();
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this?  `e.which` in the `keypress()` is what you're looking for to see what button is pressed. in this case, `13` is equivalent to the enter key

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add').on('click', function() {
        var html = '<input type="text" class="field" /><br/><br/>';
        $('.form').append(html);
    });
    $(document).on("keypress", ".field", function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            $('.add').trigger('click');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="add" href="#">add</a><br/><br/>
<div class="form">
    <input type="text" class="field" /><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" class="field" /><br/><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not bind the event keypress to the input element added dynemically, see my answer..

Answer (score 1):

You cant detect enter keypress on the input and trigger the button's click event.

```js
$("button").on("click", function(e){
  $("body").append($("<input>").attr("type", "text"));
});

$(document).on("keypress", "input", function(e){
  if(e.which == 13) $("button").trigger("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add Input</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var i;
var inputs=document.getElementsByClassName('add');

for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
  inputs[i].addEventListener('keyup',function(event){
    
    if(event.keyCode){if (event.keyCode=="13" ){createNewElem();
      }}
            
      //if(event.which){if(event.which =="13"){alert('return pressed');}}
    
    });
  }
function createNewElem(){
   
  var newinput=document.createElement('input');
  var inptype=document.createAttribute('type');
  inptype.value="text"; 
  newinput.setAttributeNode(inptype);
  var inpclass=document.createAttribute('class');
  inpclass.value="add"; 
  newinput.setAttributeNode(inpclass);
  document.body.appendChild(newinput);
  
   
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="add" />
```