# SImulate "Enter pressing" when submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, button, submit

When my submit Button in the form is clicked, I need to simulate that the "Enter button" is pressed. so: clicking on the submit form is equal to pressing Enter on the keyboard. Because I want to have the same method for both...

Here is what I have, but until now it doesnt works..

```
$(document).on('click', '#send', function(){
$("#chatMessageTextarea").focus();
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 13;
e.keyCode = 13;
```

});

Comment: You don't need this. You can simply use `$('form').submit();`

Comment: how do you mean this ?

Comment: What is it that you are ultimately trying to achieve here?

Comment: if somebody clicks on my submit button, it should simulate that the user pressed enter and not clicked on the submit button, u understand?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631589/detect-enter-key-is-pressed-with-jquery

Comment: For me, this makes no sense. If your button is clicked, you can call another method or function instead of emulate a key trigger. I don't understand it!

Comment: PLEASE: I want that if the button is clicked, it should automatically press the enter on the keyboard, without the user. is this inpossible?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, not tested it, hope it helps!

```
function keyUpFunc(e) {
var keyCode_Enter = 13;
    if (e.keyCode === keyCode_Enter) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#send').trigger("click");                    
    }
}         

$(document).keyup(keyUpFunc);

$(document).on('click', '#send', function(){
    // Click Event handler for send
});
```

Comment: you can set the keyupfunc for a perticular field as well instead of document if thats what you require.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to achieve here. But if you want that I think this link has answer to simulate keypress via jQuery.

[Definitive way to trigger keypress events with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery)

Copied code from link:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 13; // # Some key code value
$("input").trigger(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#send', function(){
   $("#chatMessageTextarea").trigger({
        type: "keypress", 
        which: 13, 
        keyCode: 13});
});
```

hope it helps!